# Allow only numbers and special character(-) to be typed in a textbox

Tags: javascript

I need to Allow only numbers and special character minus "-" to be typed in a textbox, plz help me i already have a number restriction, but wanna minus sign too.

thanks in advance

```
<script>
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>


<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Comment: Try using regex maybe?

Comment: You should have a look at the HTML5 [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) attribute.

Comment: could u plz help me with the same code using regex

Comment: pattern has browser support issue in IE old versions and not support in opera

Comment: I didnt get u Jonas w

Comment: Looks like you just copy + paste a code you did not understand. You just need to add another && charCode !==45 and it will work.

Comment: right Jonas it helps me and I already solved it, and thanks for your harsh words too

Comment: @jai im glad to hear that youve solved it. However,  i did not want to be harsh in any way, im sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `!=45` is not sufficient. You need to prevent the acceptance of invalid key inputs too. Returning true/false will still allow user to type those keys and your code then will seem to do nothing.

```
if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 45) {
   evt.preventDefault();
}
```

This way only valid key inputs will appear in text box.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will check for numbers and '-'. If there are other characters, they'll be replaced.

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^(\d|-)+$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
    }
});
```

No jQuery version:

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeyup="isNumber()" />

function isNumber() {
    var inputField = document.getElementById('extra7');
    if (!inputField.value.match(/^(\d|-)+$/)) {
        inputField.value = inputField.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
    }
}
```

Comment: if no `jquery` is tagged Q&A is supposed to be in plain JS.

Comment: @niksofteng right, added it